# Grey zone of DST

Tags: c#, timezone, dst

does anybody knows how to handle grey zones of DST (when time doesn't exist):
e.g.:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014,3,30,2,30,0);
TimeZoneInfo tziSV = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
DateTime dtSV =TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt,tziSV);
```

gives an error,when

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014,3,30,2,30,0);
dt = dt.ToUniversalTime();
dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt,tziSV);
```

gives 1:30 and then 3:30.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of handling this grey zones by .net facilities

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014,3,30,2,30,0);
    TimeZoneInfo tziSV = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");

    if (tziSV.IsInvalidTime(dt))
    {
       dt = dt.Add(tziSV.GetUtcOffset(dt));
    }
    DateTime dtSV = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt,tziSV);
```

Comment: I very much doubt that you want to add the whole UTC offset. For example, in California that would change the time by 7 or 8 hours (depending on what GetUtcOffset does for invalid times). What *exactly* do you want the result to be? (Using `IsInvalidTime` is the right way of spotting it though.)

Answer (score 4):

Use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) :)

That doesn't relieve you from the burden of *thinking* how you want to handle this - but it allows you to *specify* how you want to handle it. Fundamentally, you've been given a value that doesn't exist... so you can choose to throw an error, or maybe take the start of the transition, or the end of the transition, or some custom behaviour:

For example, the "lenient" resolver will return the end of the transition:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var local = new LocalDateTime(2014, 3, 30, 2, 30, 0);
        var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Paris"];

        var zoned = local.InZoneLeniently(zone);
        Console.WriteLine(zoned);  // 2014-03-30T03:00:00 Europe/Paris (+02)
    }
}
```

Or you could use a built-in resolver to return "just before" the transition:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.TimeZones;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var local = new LocalDateTime(2014, 3, 30, 2, 30, 0);
        var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Paris"];

        var resolver = Resolvers.CreateMappingResolver(
              ambiguousTimeResolver: Resolvers.ReturnEarlier,
              skippedTimeResolver: Resolvers.ReturnEndOfIntervalBefore);
        var zoned = local.InZone(zone, resolver);
        Console.WriteLine(zoned); // 2014-03-30T01:59:59 Europe/Paris (+01)
    }
}
```

Or you can build your own resolver (they're just delegates).

Fundamentally it's up to your application to work out how it needs to handle this. There's no one-size-fits-all answer, and you can't easily avoid losing data here. (Well, not without building your own data structure specifically to remember the original local date/time.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, you are right. The reason why we cannot use it, because problem appeared in the big project which have existed for ages, and introducing of another library isn't convenient.

Comment: @user470071: You might want to write extension methods on `DateTime` or `TimeZoneInfo` to allow the same behaviour then. I see you've found `IsInvalidTime` which is appropriate for spotting it - but you need to work out exactly what behaviour you want. Also remember that daylight saving time doesn't have to be 1 hour - I think it *is* everywhere at the moment, but I think some places have observed "double DST" in the past, and I know Nepal was considering a 75-minute saving.